# Download file from a HTML GET method with Matlab

Tags: html, matlab, download, get

I've used StackOverflow for long but I've never had to ask because there is a lot of already answered questions.

Now I am stuck in a Matlab problem I cannot solve:

I am working with Google Trends and I need to **download a CSV file with Matlab**, as the one you can download from the following link:

https://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=es&q=dji&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2&content=1&export=1

which is easy to get from its page ( https://www.google.es/trends/explore#q=ford )

**My problem is**:
**I can download it with any browser**, even Matlab web browser works, **however I haven't found a way to automatize that download**.

I have tried with *urlread()* and I get an HTML file instead of a CSV file:

```
<html><head><title>Redireccionando</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      // Accessing window.external members can cause IE to throw exceptions.
      // Any code that acesses window.external members must be try/catch wrapped
      /** @preserveTry */
      try {
        if (top == self) {
          if (window.gtbExternal) {
            window.gtbExternal.setM();
          } else {
            window.external.setM();
          }
        }
      }
      catch(err) {
      }
    </script>

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=&#39;https://www.google.com/trends#q=dji&amp;hl=es&amp;tz=Etc/GMT-2&amp;content=1&#39;"></head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000cc" vlink="#551a8b" alink="#ff0000"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    location.replace("https://www.google.com/trends#q\x3ddji\x26hl\x3des\x26tz\x3dEtc/GMT-2\x26content\x3d1")
  </script></body></html>
```

I have also tried with *urlread2()* which I found around here, and also with a *downloadUrl()* function that looks like it is based on Java, but my Java knowledge is tiny and I have no idea of what that function does or if I can modify it to suit my problem.

I'm sure someone has already solved that problem in Matlab but I have not been able to find a solution on my own by now. **I guess that it is something related to the GET method** which I do not know how to handle properly.

Comment: Do you have wget on your PC? Try `csv = system(['wget -O- ',url])`, where url is the link to CSV.

Comment: You may need options `--no-check-certificate --cookies=on --load-cookies=./cookies.txt` to pretend to be fetch the url in web browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your code opening up a window in your system browser, you can automate the download by

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=es&q=dji&tz=Etc%2FGMT-2&content=1&export=1'
web(url, '-browser');
```

The problem with using `urlread` (or `webread`, which is preferred) is that your link doesn't actually point to the CSV file you want to download; it points to a webpage which contains redirection Javascript. That page is what you see above when you run `urlread`. When you load this in a browser, the Javascript is executed, which redirects to another page and ultimately the CSV file is generated. But `urlread` and `webread`  will not execute the Javascript. As far as I know, Matlab can't execute Javascript directly, hence you may need to open a browser to execute the Javascript and generate the CSV file.

Comment: If I need to it 15 times every hour (for example). Would this open 15 browsers? In other words: Can I close the browser once the file is downloaded?

Comment: If you're using Internet Explorer you can try `ie=actxserver('internetexplorer.Application'); ie.Navigate2(url);` and then `ie.Quit;` after downloading  [See here](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/82477). You could also try using the Matlab browser which would be something like `[~, h] = web(url);` and then `close(h)` , but I'm not sure if the file gets downloaded in that case